# Why is the Hagia Sophia decision of Turkey attracting so much attention around the world?

Tags: turkey, religion

- [In Spain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_of_mosques_into_non-Islamic_places_of_worship), there are numerous mosques converted into churches.
- [TRT compiled a list of Islamic landmarks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DacAyn0RA2U) in Greece which were converted into various things including an adult film studio.
- In India, [they destroyed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demolition_of_the_Babri_Masjid) a [16th-century Mosque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babri_Masjid) and built a temple on top of that.

As far as I know (correct me if I am wrong), no country gave any official statement against those moves, although those cases made limited appearances in the international media.

Also, I noticed that a lot of foreign TV channels ([Euronews](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAp5DGTWASM), [Reuters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKsnboABGgs), [Ruptly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UxPlw3PhzQ), [CTGN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GKtCDXPspTQ), [Sputnik](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TSQxgXzVbco), [Vertizone TV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFAaCdOrwgk)) live-streamed the Friday prayer of Hagia Sophia.

So, why is [Turkey's decision to turn the Hagia Sophia back into a mosque](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-53375739) attracting so much attention around the world?

Comment: Comments deleted, purged and killed with fire. Do not use comments for attacking other users, their home-countries or cultures.

Answer (score 16):

The most obvious objective difference is that Babri Masjid was destroyed in 1992. That event [was discussed](https://www.nytimes.com/1992/12/07/world/hindu-militants-destroy-mosque-setting-off-a-new-crisis-in-india.html) in international media at the time. Now it's old news, Hagia Sofia is not.

Another possible diffence is that Hagia Sofia is, in my experience, much more internationally famous. It is arguably as famous as the Taj Mahal. As far as I can tell the Babri Masjid, however important it may have been, was not a UNESCO world heritage site as these other two are. [The UNESCO statement against Turkey's decision](https://en.unesco.org/news/unesco-statement-hagia-sophia-istanbul) is just one angle that makes the story newsworthy.

So if something bad happened to the Taj Mahal and the international media were to ignore it, that would be very surprising. That is not the case here at all. If the question is meant to imply that the international media is biased against Muslims, that may or not be the case, but it is clearly not the reason Hagia Sofia is in the news.

Answer (score 13):

Please study the [history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagia_Sophia#History) of the Hagia Sophia. It was original a Christian church, and the Orthodox Churches have [voiced concerns](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2020/07/world-reacts-turkey-reconverting-hagia-sophia-mosque-200710135637861.html) about the recent events. In short: It's complicated.

Turkey is officially a *secular* country, so reversing the transformation into a museum by *Atatürk* can be seen as another step in converting Turkey into a Muslim state.

Comment: It was not just any Christian church. It was the center of the Orthodox branch from its inauguration in 537 until 1453 when Constantinople fell to the Ottomans. There had been major Christian churches on the site from 360 until 1453.